# Javascript - where does getDomElement link to here?

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, return

I am just working on getting my head around Object Orientated Javascript and I have some sample code to work through.

A section of it is posted below which creates a button, this all works fine, but when I try to re-create it, I can't place where the reference `getDomElement` comes from after the `this` keyword.

Can someone help me with this please?

Thank :-)

To clarify - the `getDomElement` does not appear to be a variable, yet it works. Is this a property of some sort?

```
var SaveButton = function(value, click_action){
   var _dom_element = document.createElement("input");
       _dom_element.type = "button";
       _dom_element.value = value;

 _dom_element.onclick = function(){
        click_action.call(null);
    };

 this.getDomElement = function() {
      return _dom_element;
 };
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't place where the reference getDomElement comes from after the this keyword"?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is not working? I tried to made sample here.. http://jsfiddle.net/rLnodj0x/

Comment: Is the getDomElement suppose to refer to say a variable? How does JavaScript know what to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SaveButton is a constructor function which creates the `input` type `button` in your case. You're passing the value and the click event handler to that constructor function.

Here, `_dom_element` is a local variable to that function. And you're binding the click event to it.

Now to your question:

```
 this.getDomElement = function() {
      return _dom_element;
 };
```

`getDomElement` is a property of that constructor function. This is attached to all buttons you're going to create using the constructor. 
As the `_dom_element` is private/local to that function alone, `getDomElement` acts as an api to get reference to that `button`.

> How does JavaScript know what to do with that?

It's just a property attached to that constructor function. So when you call

```
var button = new SaveButton("value", callbackfunction);

var reference = button.getDomElement();

// reference.style.background do anything with that button now.
```

It will look for the property in that button object and invoke that function. In turn when you create an object using constructor function a scope is created for that object. So the property `getDomElement` will be part of that scope and would be able to return you the `_dom_element` reference.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer and +1 for adding to your answer after I updated the question ;-)